# Can someone explain to me what's the proper usage of gRPC StreamObserver.onError?

Tags: error-handling, grpc-java

I am trying to handle gRPC errors properly (Java, Spring-boot app).

Basically, I need too transfer error details from gRPC server to client, but I find it hard to understand the proper usage of `StreamObserver.onError();`

The method doc says:

> "Receives a terminating error from the stream. May only be called once
> and if called it must be the last method called. In particular if an
> exception is thrown by an implementation of onError no further calls
> to any method are allowed."

What does this **"no further calls are allowed"** mean? In the app that I maintain, they call other gRPC methods and they get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: call already closed` which is just fine, as per documentation.

I am wondering - should I (the developer) terminate the current java method (which usus gRPC calls) after an error is received? Like for example throwing an exception to stop execution. Or it is expected tht gRPC is going to terminate the execution.. (something like throwing an exception from gRPC)

Basically how do I properly use `onError()` and what should I expect and handle if I call it?
I need an explanation of its usage and effects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two `StreamObserver` instances involved. One is for the inbound direction, which is the `StreamObserver` instance *you implement* and pass to the gRPC library. This is the `StreamObserver` containing your logic for how to handle responses. The other is for the outbound direction, which is the `StreamObserver` instance that *gRPC library returns to you* when calling the RPC method. This is the `StreamObserver` that you use to send requests. Most of the time, these two `StreamObserver`s are interacting with each other (e.g., in a fully duplexed streaming call, the response `StreamObserver` usually calls the request `StreamObserver`'s `onNext()` method, this is how you achieve ping-pong behavior).

"no further calls are allowed" means you should not call any more `onNext()`, `onComplete()` and/or `onError()` *on the outbound direction `StreamObserver`* when the inbound `StreamObserver`'s `onError()` method is invoked, even if your implementation for the inbound `onError()` throws an exception. Since the inbound `StreamObserver` is invoked asynchronously, it has nothing to do with your method that encloses the `StreamObserver`'s implementation.

For example:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
  private final HelloWorldStub stub;
  private StreamObserver<HelloRequest> requestObserver;

  ...

  private void sendRequest(String message) {
    requestObserver.onNext(HelloRequest.newBuilder.setMessage(message).build());
  }

  public void start() {
    stub.helloWorld(new StreamObserver<HelloResponse> {
      @Override
      public void onNext(HelloResponse response) {
        sendRequest("hello from client");
        // Optionally you can call onCompleted() or onError() on 
        // the requestObserver to terminate the call.
      }

      @Override
      public void onCompleted() {
        // You should not call any method on requestObserver.
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable error) {
        // You should not call any method on requestObserver.
      }
    });
  }

}
```

It has nothing to do with the `start()` method.

The doc is also mentioning that you should not do things like

```java
try {
  requestObserver.onCompleted();
} catch(RuntimeException e) {
  requestObserver.onError();
}
```

It's mostly for user's own `StreamObserver` implementations. `StreamObserver`'s returned by gRPC never throws.

Comment: Thanks! That is a great answer! Please, elaborate a bit more - if `onError()` is called on the outbound observer, no more gRPC methods **should** be called from the outbound observer, right? but the execution of the method wrapping the `outboundObserver.onError()` is not halted by the  `outboundObserver.onError()`, it should be stopped otherwise (like with `throw new RuntimeException()`)? I am asking this, because I have a method full of `outboundObserver.onError()` after which the method containing them is not terminated.

Comment: `outboundObserver.onError()` is notifying the server with an error, aka, sends an error to the server and close the RPC stream. The _RPC call_ is terminated. It does not cause anything to happen on the client side and does not affect the application code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what I needed to know!

Comment: where in the docs does it say you shouldn't do the oncompelted and onerror?

Answer (score 0):

I've extracted a [template for GRPC streaming](https://github.com/trajano/grpc-chunker-java) which sort of abstracts away a lot of the GRPC boilerplate that also addresses the the logic for `onError`.  In the [DechunkingStreamObserver](https://github.com/trajano/grpc-chunker-java/blob/master/src/main/java/net/trajano/grpcchunker/DechunkingStreamObserver.java)

I use the following general pattern for GRPC streaming which is something along the lines of

```
META DATA DATA DATA META DATA DATA DATA
```

An example of where I would use it would be to take one form and transform it to another form.

```proto
message SavedFormMeta {
  string id = 1;
}

message SavedFormChunk {
  oneof type {
    SavedFormMeta meta = 1;
    bytes data = 2;
  }
}

rpc saveFormDataStream(stream SavedFormChunk) returns (stream SavedFormChunk) {}
```

I use a flag that would track the `inError` state to prevent further processing and catch exceptions on the `onNext` and `onComplete` both of which I redirect to `onError` which forwards the error to the server side.

The code below pulls the GRPC semantics and takes lamdas that do the processing.

```
/**
 * Dechunks a GRPC stream from the request and calls the consumer when a complete object is created.  This stops
 * further processing once an error has occurred.
 *
 * @param <T> entity type
 * @param <R> GRPC chunk message type
 * @param <S> GRPC message type for response streams
 */
class DechunkingStreamObserver<T, R, S> implements StreamObserver<R> {

    /**
     * This function takes the current entity state and the chunk and returns a copy of the combined result.  Note the combiner may modify the existing data, but may cause unexpected behaviour.
     */
    private final BiFunction<T, R, T> combiner;

    /**
     * A function that takes in the assembled object and the GRPC response observer.
     */
    private final BiConsumer<T, StreamObserver<S>> consumer;

    /**
     * Predicate that returns true if it is a meta chunk indicating a start of a new object.
     */
    private final Predicate<R> metaPredicate;

    /**
     * this function gets the meta chunk and supplies a new object.
     */
    private final Function<R, T> objectSupplier;

    /**
     * GRPC response observer.
     */
    private final StreamObserver<S> responseObserver;

    /**
     * Currently being processed entity.
     */
    private T current = null;

    /**
     * In error state.  Starts {@code false}, but once it is set to {@code true} it stops processing {@link #onNext(Object)}.
     */
    private boolean inError = false;

    /**
     * @param metaPredicate    predicate that returns true if it is a meta chunk indicating a start of a new object.
     * @param objectSupplier   this function gets the meta chunk and supplies a new object
     * @param combiner         this function takes the current entity state and the chunk and returns a copy of the combined result.  Note the combiner may modify the existing data, but may cause unexpected behaviour.
     * @param consumer         a function that takes in the assembled object and the GRPC response observer.
     * @param responseObserver GRPC response observer
     */
    DechunkingStreamObserver(
            final Predicate<R> metaPredicate,
            final Function<R, T> objectSupplier,
            final BiFunction<T, R, T> combiner,
            final BiConsumer<T, StreamObserver<S>> consumer,
            final StreamObserver<S> responseObserver) {

        this.metaPredicate = metaPredicate;
        this.objectSupplier = objectSupplier;
        this.combiner = combiner;
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.responseObserver = responseObserver;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

        if (inError) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (current != null) {
                consumer.accept(current, responseObserver);
            }
            responseObserver.onCompleted();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            onError(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {

        responseObserver.onError(throwable);
        inError = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(final R chunk) {

        if (inError) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (metaPredicate.test(chunk)) {
                if (current != null) {
                    consumer.accept(current, responseObserver);
                }
                current = objectSupplier.apply(chunk);
            } else {
                current = combiner.apply(current, chunk);
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            onError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have 4 lamdas

- `Predicate<R> metaPredicate` which takes in a chunk and returns whether the chunk is meta or not.
- `Function<R, T> objectSupplier` which takes in a meta chunk and creates a new object that is used by your module.
- `BiFunction<T, R, T> combiner,` which takes in a data chunk and the current object and returns a new object that contains the combination.
- `BiConsumer<T, StreamObserver<S>> consumer` which will consume a completed object.  It also passes in a stream observer in the case of sending new objects in response.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you want to do is mark as `return` after calling the `responseObserver.onError();` like below. because there is nothing to do after sending the error.

```java
if(condition){
    responseObserver.onError(StatusProto.toStatusException(status));
    //this is the required part
    return;
}else{
   responseObserver.onComplete(DATA);
}
```